# different behavior, datefield 5.0.1->5.1

Tags: qooxdoo

(sorry my english) Hi.

I have big problem with 5.1 datefield. I need type dates manually, and 5.1 have behavior problems. With default global locale "en", default medium date format, enter manually a invalid date, delete manually the string, and try enter date again. The problem appear.

If I set locale to "es" with
qx.locale.Manager.getInstance().addLocale("es", {"cldr_date_format_medium": "d/M/yyyy"}), the behavior is better, but I get another problem:

With 5.0.1, if I type "3/9/70" at a datefield, this is a valid date.

With 5.1, if I type "3/9/70" at a datefield, this is a invalid date, value = null.

This have another consequences with the use of form and form controller.
I dont know if consequences exist using validators, etc.

I want subclass 5.1 datefield and add my own behavior (the old behavior), but I cant catch where I must touch, where is the significative difference.
Any help, please.
Thanks

[Playground basic example for testing](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520doc%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520form%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Form()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520dtf%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.DateField()%253B%250D%250Aform.add(dtf%252C%2520%2522Date%2522%252C%2520null%252C%2520%2522date%2522)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520button%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522View%2522)%253B%250D%250Abutton.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520alert(dtf.getValue().toString())%253B%250D%250A%257D)%253B%250D%250Aform.addButton(button)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Adoc.add(new%2520qx.ui.form.renderer.Single(form)%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252010%252C%2520top%253A%252010%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520controller%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.data.controller.Form(null%252C%2520form)%253B%250D%250Acontroller.createModel(true)%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)

Comment: Either I don't understand the problem, or the playground example works for me in *devel* and *current*. As there is no 5.1 release (it is the version set in current *master* branch), it would be better to place this in the issue tracker, rather than in stackoverflow.

Comment: put the playground example in two default new projects, version 5.0.1 and 5.1. Put global locale to "es", both project. Compare datefield behavior